# Column name is masked in oracle indexes

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have a table in oracle db which has a unique index composed of two columns (`id` and `valid_from`). The column valid_from is of type timestamps with time zone.
When I query the SYS.USER_IND_COLUMNS  to see which columns my table is using as unique index, I can not see the name of the `valid_from` column but instead I see smth like **SYS_NC00027$.**

Is there any possibility that I can display the name **valid_from**  rather than **SYS_NC00027$.** ?

Comment: Can you include the actual result of querying the `USER_IND_COLUMNS` view?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Oracle creates a function based index for `timestamp with time zone` columns.

The definition of them can be found in the view `ALL_IND_EXPRESSIONS`

Something like this should get you started:

```
select ic.index_name, 
       ic.column_name,
       ie.column_expression
from all_ind_columns ic
  left join all_ind_expressions ie 
    on ie.index_owner = ic.index_owner
   and ie.index_name = ic.index_name
   and ie.column_position = ic.column_position
where ic.table_name = 'FOO';
```

Unfortunately `column_expression` is a (deprecated) `LONG` column and cannot easily be used in a `coalesce()` or `nvl()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below to verify the col info.

```
select column_name,virtual_column,hidden_column,data_default from user_tab_cols where table_name='EMP';
```